# Childbrowser with Cordova 1.7 iPhone issue

Tags: iphone, cordova, childbrowser

Can any expert here please point me to some valid walkthrough on how to make the ChildBrowser work with Cordova 1.7 in iPhone? I have found lots of documents and blogs out there that tell you how to do it, but none of them have worked for me. It is not a whitelist issue for sure, as for the time being I have set it to the wildcard *, so whitelisting problems can be safely ruled out I guess. In some cases, ChildBrowser was successfully installed, but when I called the `showwebpage` function, it just would not show up (there wouldn't be any errors either!). Other times, it just won't even install. I have already spent 2 days on it, and am still clueless. Just hoping if you could help me out. Any help would be appreciated.

---

I could finally get the ChildBrowser to open up following what Dhawal has suggested below. But the `onLocationChange` event never seems to fire. Again, this seems to be a common problem with Cordova 1.7. Any workarounds apart from rolling back to some older Cordova version? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url, { showLocationBar: true });
window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){ alert("In index.html new loc = " + loc); };
```

---

Ok, got it to work. Seems like ChildBrowser is still compatible with older versions of Cordova only. Had to delve into Objective-C and make changes in the plugin to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a basic application which has childbrowser integration with Cordova 1.7. I have put the steps also to generate build same application.

[ios-cordova-childbrowser](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/ios-cordova-childbrowser)

### Edit

Childbrowser events were not getting called properly so I added this fix in ChildBrowser.js file to resolve it.

```
if (cordovaRef && cordovaRef.addConstructor) {
    cordovaRef.addConstructor(ChildBrowser.install);

    // Make ChildBrowser global
    window.ChildBrowser = ChildBrowser;
 } else {
    console.log("ChildBrowser Cordova Plugin could not be installed.");
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, works like a charm now. I would also vote up if i had the reputations :)

Comment: Can you please help me with my latest roadblock now? Please see the edit.

Comment: i have fixed the project and updated the github source, also adding the change in the answer if you want to just add the fix

Comment: let me know if it works for you, it is calling proper events in my setup

Comment: Yes it does, this seems simpler than making changes in the .m files of the plugin, which is what i did in trying to get it to work. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @dhaval,  voted it up.  thank you for the elegant one-line fix in childbrowser.js.  I am a newbie and don't know how to do this. But it would help a lot of people if, your fix at:  https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/blob/master/ios-cordova-childbrowser/www/ChildBrowser.js  can   be pulled into   https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/ChildBrowser/ChildBrowser.js.   It took a a while to stumble upon your fix. Thanks again.