# Childbrowser ＋ Cordova 1.8.1 iPhone4S(iOS5.1) issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova 1.8.1 in xcode 4.3.3 and trying to add the ChildBrowser Plugin to my phonegap app.The ChildBrowser plugin I’m using is [here](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser) which I think is the latest version of ChildBrowser and I follow the tutorial [here](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/) to make sure it works on iOS Simulator 5.1,but can not open a link.

Here's my example index.html code....

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var childbrowser;

function onBodyLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

}

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");
}

function onLinkClick() {
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){ alert("In index.html new loc = " + loc); };
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = function(){alert("In index.html child browser closed");};
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal = function(){alert("In index.html onOpenExternal");};        

    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.com',
                                    { showLocationBar: true });
    console.log(window.plugins.childBrowser);

}
</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the ChildBrowser up and running?

Any help is greatly appreciated,thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sample application working with childbrowser at this location with the steps to make it work in any application.

[ios-child-browser](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/ios-cordova-childbrowser)

For more detail check this post - [Childbrowser with Cordova 1.7 iPhone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027479/childbrowser-with-cordova-1-7-iphone-issue/)

Comment: Thx,that's quite helpful.the sample application works and now I'm trying to figure out What's wrong with me on Installing the ChildBrowser Plugin and I'm sorry for that I can't vote your anser up,because I don't have enough reputation to do that.Anyway thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that most of my mistakes were based on those old blog posts, so I wrote a blog post about how to Installing the ChildBrowser for iOS/xcode with PhoneGap/Cordova 1.8.1 and 1.9.0 step by step.                                        
 check this post -- [Installing the ChildBrowser for iOS/xcode with PhoneGap/Cordova 1.8.1 and 1.9.0](http://www.3ch.me/2012/07/newest-way-to-installing-childbrowser.html)

hopefully this helps someone.